# Sent ETH from Lykke with smart contract to Binance.com. Account still not credited? What to do?

Tags: contract-invocation, recovery

Is my ETH lost if the receiving exchange company does not recognize smart contracts?
is there a way to reverse transaction or recover the ETH sent?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it for 3rd-party application/service support.

Comment: Contact the support and don't give up, they should recover your ETH. See this related thread on reddit: [reddit.com/r/bitfinex/comments/6vi7sy/sent_ether_from_bitstamp_to_bitfinex_not_aware_of/](https://www.reddit.com/r/bitfinex/comments/6vi7sy/sent_ether_from_bitstamp_to_bitfinex_not_aware_of/)

Answer (score 1):

In principle, there is no reason why an exchange should not accept founds coming **from** a smart contract. So either your smart contract has gone out of gas and your funds have never been sent, or the exchange should have received it.